# Powershell: can i get ip adress from inactive network adapter with Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration?

Tags: powershell, ip, ip-address, get-wmiobject

Powershell: Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration only shows the ip address of active network adapters. Get-netipaddress shows ip-address of all network adapters (also the disconnected once), but is there a way to get all ip adresses of all network adapters with Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration?

Comment: If the adapter is configured for a dynamic IP address, (which is most likely, otherwise you won't need to query it) supplied by the remote (disconnected) DHCP server, I assume that it isn't available...